# Undefined method 'where'

Tags: ruby, activemodel

I have this:

```
def self.testing    
    nodo = Attribute.where(:product_attribute_type_id => 7, :value => 1)  
end
```

in a **Product class** method, then I load **Attribute Class** before a load Product class, then I call the testing method:

```
a = Product.testing
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined method `where' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute:Class
```

Pointing at testing method, I read some errors and question here, but I don't get error.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is `Attribute` a model ? It seems that `Attribute` is not a model class.

Comment: Yes, It's a class. Also I bold the text where I describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `Attribute` supposed to be ? You just want to call `where` (or `self.where`), not `Attribute.where`.

Where did you see this method of definining scopes?

NOTE : Oh, I think I get it. You have a model named `Attribute` -- That won't fly by ActiveRecord. You could always use it by saying `::Attribute`, but it's going to break at some point.

Comment: Attribute is another class, deriving from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Is it one of your class ? You can't name of your models `Attribute`; I'm afraid

Comment: Ummm I trying the code out of a class method (out of Product class), and works fine

Comment: because that class isn't inheriting `ActiveRecord::Base`, right ? :)

Comment: Product and Attribute inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Yeah - Not what I'm saying. What I'm asking is -  when you extract the code out of Product, you're not in ActiveRecord::Base anymore, right ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm out that, in a simple file that load the class Attribute and use the method

Comment: Exactly What I'm saying. `Attribute` is reserved because when you're in the context of `ActiveRecord::Base`, you get all the constants AR has "imported", etc. Do you understand ?

Comment: Completely!!  Thanks for your helping.